# Pandas, Fill Boolean Value compare two row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, broadcasting

My data is

```
        A      B
1   False   True
2   False   True
3   False   True
4   False   True
5    True  False
6    True  False
7   False   True
8    True  False
9    True   True
10  False   True
11  False   True
12  False   True
13   True  False
14   True  False
15  False  False
16  False  False
17  False  False
```

My code is

```
data.loc[(data['B']== False) & (data['B'].shift(1) == True), 'A'] = True
data.loc[(data['A'].shift(1)== True) & (data['B'].shift(1) == False),'A'] = True
```

My desire result is row No. 15,16,17 is True,

```
        A      B
1   False   True
2   False   True
3   False   True
4   False   True
5    True  False
6    True  False
7   False   True
8    True  False
9    True   True
10  False   True
11  False   True
12  False   True
13   True  False
14   True  False
15  **True**  False
16  **True**  False
17  **True**  False
```

Once 'A' is "True" then A is "True" before meet "B" is "True" and "B" become "True" then "A" turn into "False"

is there any simple solution for solving this?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: Yes, but *why* are 15,16,17 going to be True? Is it because you want to change `data.A` to `True` where both `data.A` and `data.B` are False?

Comment: Why dont need only `data.loc[(data['B']== False), 'A'] = True` ?

Comment: I recommend trying harder at explaining what's going on.